# Bluetooth audio without pulse?

Tags: raspbian, bluetooth, alsa

Is there any way I can connect to my Bluetooth headphones and listen to audio without using pulseaudio?

I also can't use a GUI because reasons.

Also, I'm on Raspbian Jessie minimal.

Comment: Try this: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bluetooth_headset#Headset_and_ALSA_Devices  I'd assume it would then also show up as a device with `alsamixer` (which is a TUI, so you can use easily via `ssh`, etc).